# Why is the PMF of the Poisson distribution proportional to the exponential Taylor series.

Tags: probability, exponential-function, poisson-distribution

Looking at the PMF of the Poisson distribution:

$$P(X=x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} =e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$

The $\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$ is the $x$-th term in the Taylor expansion of the exponential function. And the $e^{-\lambda}$ normalizes those terms and makes them sum to $1$.

Is there an intuitive reason why the terms of the Poisson PMF must be proportional to the Taylor expansion of the exponential function? Perhaps through the Poisson process?

Comment: The poisson distribution can be deduced mathematically from the binomial distribution. There is no intuitve, non-mathematical reason for the taylor expansion of $e^{\lambda}$, IMHO.

Comment: This is just what happens with an exponential family on nonnegative integers generated by the measure $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\delta_n(dx)$. If $L(\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}a_n\lambda ^n$  the probability corresponding to $\lambda$ is $$\Pr(X=n)=\frac{1}{L(\lambda)}a_n\lambda^n$$: nothing special here for the Poisson distributions.